# Reduce SQL Server transaction log file size from my c# application

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to reduce the size of my SQL Server database transaction log file, but I want to do this from my C# application periodically. Shortly after publishing my application, the transaction log file size increases too quickly.

To solve this problem, I want to create a scheduled task in my application to decrease the size of the log files in Visual Studio 2010 and SQL Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than truncating your transaction log file, you should just set the database to `SIMPLE` recovery. That will prevent the log file from growing:

```
ALTER DATABASE db SET RECOVERY SIMPLE
```